# Error importing snapshot

Tags: node, snapshots, bootstrapping

I tried to import a snapshot to bootstrap a full node but I get the following error:

```
Writing context: 38902K/38902K (100%) elements, 6811MiB read Done                                                                                                             Jan  4 19:26:41.094 - node.main: cleaning up directory "/opt/data/tezos/main" after failure. 
tezos-node: Error:                                                                     
              Failed to validate block BLQ6n88KEDX57dAVHcrhwThD4KiaQomZchfCnf56v5tdTGSTSG1: Error:
              Missing protocol (PtLimaPtLMwf) when validating the block BLQ6n88KEDX5.
```

The client version is :

```
$ tezos-node --version                                                                                        
4ca33194 (2022-08-01 11:55:43 +0200) (14.0)
```

I used the full snapshot of nomadics lab (https://lambsonacid.nl/) as indicated in the documentation (https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/snapshots.html)

I used the following command:

```
$ tezos-node snapshot import /opt/data/tezos/tezos.snapshot --data-dir=/opt/data/tezos/main
```

Is the problem the version of my node ? Because some snapshot providers do not indicate which was the version of the node used to make the snapshot

Comment: You probably need tezos/octez node version 15.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snapshot depends on the node (and protocol) version.

Make sure the node is using the same version.